# How can you stop dual pocket doors so they close in the center and do not come off the track

Tags: doors, pocket-door

New pocket doors installed, but if you close the doors and maybe one is beyond the center, it comes off the track. What can be done to stop the doors in the center?

Comment: Well, clearly the stop can't be something you could trip over.... so it has to either stop the top of the door, or catch the back edge if the door somehow. The former seems easier, almost to the point of being obvious...?

Answer (score 1):

Usually there is a metal stop (like an angle bracket) inside the top track area that stops each door at the center. If you cut away the top corner of the door you could use wood, metal is thin enough that it's often not bothered with, or could be done (if looking for perfect closure) but is a much smaller cut.

You could also block the track to stop the wheels at the proper position, but it's harder to get right.

Comment: Your last part of the comment is what we done at the company I last worked at. It is tough to get it right, but when secured properly, it work very well and is out of sight. For the Johnson 1000 series track for example, it took a piece of wood about 3-4" long, 7/8" or 1" deep secured in edgewise. Trail and error tunes up the stopping points.